# Cartesian joining half of a table with data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

Assume I have the following data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  a = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
  b = c('A', 'A', NA_character_, NA_character_),
  Amount = 1:4
)
```

I want to perform a cartesian join to apply weights to the amount column, say I have the following table with weights:

```
set.seed(42L)
weights <- data.table(
  a = c(rep(1L, 5L), rep(2L, 5L)),
  b = LETTERS[1:10],
  Weight = runif(10L)
)
```

One way to get what I want is this:

```
rbind(
  dt[a == 1L],
  dt[a != 1L][
    weights,
    .(a, b = i.b, Amount = Amount * Weight),
    on = c('a'),
    nomatch = 0L,
    allow.cartesian = TRUE
  ]
)
```

**Edit:** An improvement by my colleague that is an improvement for this first item but doesn't do much for performance:

```
rbind(
  dt[a == 1L],
  dt[a != 1L][
    weights,
    modifyList(.SD, .(b = i.b, Amount = Amount * Weight)),
    on = c('a'),
    nomatch = 0L,
    allow.cartesian = TRUE
    ]
)
```

Resulting in:

```
    a b    Amount
 1: 1 A 1.0000000
 2: 1 A 2.0000000
 3: 2 F 1.5572878
 4: 2 F 2.0763838
 5: 2 G 2.2097649
 6: 2 G 2.9463533
 7: 2 H 0.4039998
 8: 2 H 0.5386664
 9: 2 I 1.9709769
10: 2 I 2.6279692
11: 2 J 2.1151944
12: 2 J 2.8202591
```

I want to know/improve two things:

1. If the number of columns grows, all columns need to be specified in the final block of code `.(a, b = i.b, Amount = Amount * Weight)` keeps on growing.
2. Is there way to do this more efficiently if the number of rows grows to millions?

Comment: I am quite confused. Does this generate desired results: `dt[, Amount := Amount + 0]; dt[weights, Amount := Amount * i.Weight, on = .(a, b)]`?

Comment: @mt1022 I don't think so, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

For qn1, maybe something like:

```
othercols <- setdiff(names(weights), "Weight")
rbindlist(list(
    dt[a == 1L],
    dt[a != 1L][
        weights,
        c(setNames(mget(paste0("i.", othercols)), othercols), .(Amount = Amount * Weight)),
        on=.(a),
        nomatch = 0L,
        allow.cartesian = TRUE
    ]
), use.names=TRUE)
```

For qn2, is there really a need for cartesian join that expands the data by so much?